# How can i parse this csv file that contains a column with a tensor value

Tags: python, pandas, deep-learning, pytorch, image-classification

To save memory in my notebook . I saved the image processing(transforming) output into a dataset to a comma-separated values file that i could load to a notebook. But after trying to parse it using various methods its still recognized as a string.

This is an example of how one tensor looks like in the comma-separated values file, it is a string:

```py
'tensor([[[-0.8849, -0.8849, -0.9192,  ..., -1.4329, -2.1179, -2.1179],\n         [-0.9192, -0.8849, -0.8678,  ..., -1.3987, -2.1179, -2.1179],\n         [-0.9020, -0.8849, -0.8678,  ..., -1.3644, -2.1179, -2.1179],\n         ...,\n         [-2.1179, -2.1179, -1.4158,  ..., -0.9877, -1.0048, -0.9877],\n         [-2.1179, -2.1179, -1.3644,  ..., -0.9877, -1.0048, -1.0048],\n         [-2.1179, -2.1179, -1.3130,  ..., -0.9705, -1.0390, -1.0390]],\n\n        [[-0.3200, -0.3200, -0.3550,  ..., -1.1779, -2.0357, -2.0357],\n         [-0.3550, -0.3200, -0.3025,  ..., -1.1604, -2.0357, -2.0357],\n         [-0.3375, -0.3200, -0.3200,  ..., -1.1604, -2.0357, -2.0357],\n         ...,\n         [-2.0357, -2.0357, -1.3004,  ..., -1.0903, -1.1078, -1.0903],\n         [-2.0357, -2.0357, -1.2829,  ..., -1.0903, -1.1078, -1.1253],\n         [-2.0357, -2.0357, -1.2654,  ..., -1.1078, -1.1779, -1.1779]],\n\n        [[-1.1944, -1.1770, -1.1770,  ..., -1.6650, -1.8044, -1.8044],\n         [-1.1944, -1.1596, -1.1247,  ..., -1.6476, -1.8044, -1.8044],\n         [-1.1421, -1.1247, -1.1073,  ..., -1.6302, -1.8044, -1.8044],\n         ...,\n         [-1.8044, -1.8044, -1.5604,  ..., -1.0724, -1.0898, -1.0724],\n         [-1.8044, -1.8044, -1.5081,  ..., -1.0724, -1.1073, -1.1073],\n         [-1.8044, -1.8044, -1.4559,  ..., -1.0724, -1.1770, -1.1770]]])'
```

this is the error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
----> 3 train_set["0"] = train_set["0"].apply(parse_tensor_string)


ValueError : could not convert string to float: '[-0.4226'
```

I tried this:

```py
def parse_tensor_string(tensor_string):

    # Extract the flattened tensor data from the string
    start_index = tensor_string.find("[[")
    end_index = tensor_string.find("]]")
    data_string = tensor_string[start_index+2:end_index]
    
    # Remove any extraneous characters
    data_string = data_string.replace("\n", "").replace("  ", "").replace(",", "")
    
    # Convert each substring to a float
    tensor_list = data_string.split()
    tensor_floats = [float(s) for s in tensor_list]
    
    # Reshape the resulting array to match the original tensor shape
    tensor_array = np.array(tensor_floats).reshape((3, 224, 224))
    
    # Return the tensor as a numpy array
    return tensor_array

train_set["0"] = train_set["0"]. apply(parse_tensor_string)
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample as raw string for your csv file

Answer (score 1):

It is unfortunately not possible from the string you provided. The string you have saved is a truncated string representation of the tensor (indicated by the symbol `...`). This means that only the "edges" of the tensor are in the string. The original tensor of the size (3, 224, 224) is simply not in the string and can not be loaded.

However, I have modified your function to parse everything that is possible from the string you have provided:

Modified code:

```py
import ast

def parse_tensor_string(data_string):
    # Remove extraneous characters
    result = data_string.replace("\n", "").replace("...", "").replace(" ", "").replace(",,", ",").replace("tensor(", "").replace(")", "")
    # Parse to list
    result = ast.literal_eval(result)
    # Convert list to tensor
    return torch.tensor(result)
```

Output:

```py
tensor([[[-0.8849, -0.8849, -0.9192, -1.4329, -2.1179, -2.1179],
         [-0.9192, -0.8849, -0.8678, -1.3987, -2.1179, -2.1179],
         [-0.9020, -0.8849, -0.8678, -1.3644, -2.1179, -2.1179],
         [-2.1179, -2.1179, -1.4158, -0.9877, -1.0048, -0.9877],
         [-2.1179, -2.1179, -1.3644, -0.9877, -1.0048, -1.0048],
         [-2.1179, -2.1179, -1.3130, -0.9705, -1.0390, -1.0390]],

        [[-0.3200, -0.3200, -0.3550, -1.1779, -2.0357, -2.0357],
         [-0.3550, -0.3200, -0.3025, -1.1604, -2.0357, -2.0357],
         [-0.3375, -0.3200, -0.3200, -1.1604, -2.0357, -2.0357],
         [-2.0357, -2.0357, -1.3004, -1.0903, -1.1078, -1.0903],
         [-2.0357, -2.0357, -1.2829, -1.0903, -1.1078, -1.1253],
         [-2.0357, -2.0357, -1.2654, -1.1078, -1.1779, -1.1779]],

        [[-1.1944, -1.1770, -1.1770, -1.6650, -1.8044, -1.8044],
         [-1.1944, -1.1596, -1.1247, -1.6476, -1.8044, -1.8044],
         [-1.1421, -1.1247, -1.1073, -1.6302, -1.8044, -1.8044],
         [-1.8044, -1.8044, -1.5604, -1.0724, -1.0898, -1.0724],
         [-1.8044, -1.8044, -1.5081, -1.0724, -1.1073, -1.1073],
         [-1.8044, -1.8044, -1.4559, -1.0724, -1.1770, -1.1770]]])
```